# Migrating MOSS 2007 to sharepoint 2010 giving the error "Site collection could not be restored"

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am trying to migrate MOSS 2007 to sharepoint 2010 and I got the error while restoring the backup. The steps I followed are

1. I have the back up file and all solution pakcages from MOSS 2007.
2. I have a brand new server setup with sharepoint 2010 and Sql server 2008(64 bit) and windows server 2008 (64 bit).
   3.I have created a new web application and new site collection.
   4.Successfully Deployed the solution packages using powershell command.
   5.trying to restore the backup and got the error

Restore-SPSite: THe site collection could not be restored, If this problem persists please make sure the content databases are available and have sufficient free space.

CAn anyone help me how to resolve this. I tried following some suggestions I got through google, but nothing worked for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly restore the moss2007 backup to sharepoint 2010. You need to restore it back to SharePoint 2007 and then migrate it. If you have a database backup of the content database, then you could follow the steps given:

- Take the backup of the content database from the SharePoint 2007
  database server.
- restore it to the database server of the 2010    environment.
- Run the cmdlet  Test-SPContentDatabase –Name -WebApplication using powershell to make sure that all the required dependencies are available on the 2010 server.
- create a new web application on the 2010 server and add the content
  database to it. upgrade the visual look of the web application by
  doing to the site settings.

I hope this will help you out.